# How is LinkedList's add(int, E) of O(1) complexity?

Tags: java, linked-list, big-o, time-complexity

From the [linked-list](/questions/tagged/linked-list) tag wiki excerpt:

> A linked list is a data structure in which the elements contain
>   references to the next (and optionally the previous) element. Linked
>   lists offer **O(1) insert and removal at any position**, O(1) list
>   concatenation, and O(1) access at the front (and optionally back)
>   positions as well as O(1) next element access. Random access has O(N)
>   complexity and is usually unimplemented.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

I was surprised to read this – how can the list *insert* at a random index with a lower complexity than simply *reading* that index?

So I looked at [the source code for `java.util.LinkedList`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/LinkedList.java). The [`add(int, E)` method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/LinkedList.java#LinkedList.add%28int%2Cjava.lang.Object%29) is:

```
public void add(int index, E element) {
    addBefore(element, (index==size ? header : entry(index)));
}
```

The [`addBefore(E, Entry<E>` method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/LinkedList.java#LinkedList.addBefore%28java.lang.Object%2Cjava.util.LinkedList.Entry%29) is simply pointer reassignment, but there's also the [`entry(int)` method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/LinkedList.java#LinkedList.entry%28int%29):

```
if (index < 0 || index >= size)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index: "+index+
                                            ", Size: "+size);
    Entry<E> e = header;
    if (index < (size >> 1)) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= index; i++)
            e = e.next;
    } else {
        for (int i = size; i > index; i--)
            e = e.previous;
    }
    return e;
}
```

Even with the half-size optimization, the `for` loop in here (one or the other) seems to me a dead giveaway that this method (and thus `add(int, E)`) operates in a minimum worst-case scenario of O(n) time, and certainly not constant time.

What am I missing? Am I misunderstanding the big-O notation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, they do support constant-time inserts at arbitrary positions – but **only if** you happen to have a pointer to the list entry after which or in front of which you want to insert something. Of course, this won't work if you just have the index, but that's not what you usually do in optimized code.

In Java, you can do that, too, but [only using a list iterator](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/LinkedList.java#768).

This property of linked lists is their biggest advantage compared to arraylists or so – for example, if you want to remove a user from the user list of a chatroom, you can store a pointer to the user's position in the userlist in the user so that, when he wants to leave the room, that can be implemented as a `O(1)` operation.

Comment: In other words: `LinkedList<E>.add(int, E)` is not O(1), but `ListIterator<E>.add` is (for iterators that come from a `LinkedList`).

Answer (score 26):

This is because the article that you are reading considered "getting to that index" as a separate operation. The article assumes that you are already at the index you wish to perform add(int, E).

To conclude:

**Insert or Remove operation = O(1)**

**Finding node at n<sup>th</sup> index = O(n)**

Comment: According to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18679284/4828060,  finding a node at nth index is O(1). Not sure yet which of the answers I agree with :|

Comment: @JoãoMatos, that particular answer was to a question asking about the complexity of the addLast() method. As java's LinkedList is a doubly linked list maintaining pointers to the first and last element, addLast() is O(1). Looking up a node at an arbitrary index is still O(n).

Answer (score 4):

The operation of **linking** the new node to any node is O(1) but the operation of **finding** (helps to the loop) the concerned index is definitely O(n).

There is no magic ;)

Answer (score 2):

The wiki page you quote says:

> O(1) insert and removal at any *position*

Then you ask:

> I was surprised to read this – how can the list insert at a random *index*

Herein lies the confusion: the terms *position* and *index* are not being used to mean the same thing. The wiki talks about  an iterator or a pointer, not about an index.

Comment: Although `position` is a bit ambiguous... and "insert ... at" suggests the index interpretation. I've suggested a tag wiki edit to clarify, what do you think about it?

Comment: @thejh: I personally think it's pretty clear. However, given that at least one person found it confusing, I don't see what harm a little clarification could do.