# Linked List time complexity for its operations

Tags: java, linked-list

I am implementing a Linked list in terms of stock market program.

It has and operation -  Buy

For Buy the code is

```
//Stocks is a linked List like so 
//LinkedList<Integer> stocks = new LinkedList<Integer>();
public void buy(int q, int p) {
    stocks.addLast(q); //add number of stocks
    stocks.addLast(p); //for i stocks i +1 = price of stock
}
```

This operation addLast is for a Linked list obvious adds the given element to a new position at the end of a current list.

So for example if I have a list that has lets say the following data

```
//Stock, price, stock, price etc...
[100, 50, 5000, 30, 8000, 60]
```

If I `addLast` is the Linked List search for the last element and then adding and therefore the time complexity would be O(n) (In terms of Big Oh only). Or is it indexing to the end of the list, realizing that the end of the list is say `stocks[5]` then inserting a new node referencing the new data at the end of the list?

So my question is, is `addLast()` operation for a linked list time complexity of O(n) or O(1)?

Post below for any clarifications

Comment: except its not getLast is it?^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you read the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) for the LinkedList class, it states: "All of the operations perform as could be expected for a doubly-linked list. Operations that index into the list will traverse the list from the beginning **or the end**, whichever is closer to the specified index."

This means that it is O(1)

**Edit**

If you want a better implementation of your Stock name, price list, I think it would be better to create a class containing the description of the stocks:

```
public class Stock {
    private int stockName;
    private int stockPrice;

    // other methods, properties, constructor
}
```

And then create a `LinkedList<Stock>`

Comment: Thank you didn't think to look in the javadoc, i'll do that next time before asking a question of this type - cheers

Comment: Any time! I have a small comment regarding your implementation of the solution though, I am adding it as an edit to my answer

Answer (score 2):

The complexity of `add()` or `addLast()` is `O(1)` on the length of the list.  This is obvious from reading the `LinkedList` [source code.](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/LinkedList.java/)

(Since this aspect of the behaviour is not specified precisely in the javadoc<sup>1</sup>, it could be changed ... in theory.  However, we can confidently exclude this possibility.  Even if it made sense (which it doesn't!), such a change would break many, many existing applications.  That alone is sufficient reason to rule it out as implausible.)

---

<sup>1 - I would argue that the javadoc sentence *"[o]perations that index into the list will traverse the list from the beginning or the end, whichever is closer to the specified index"* does not *unambiguously* apply to this method.  You could argue that the `add` / `addLast` method does not *index* into the list.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source for the LinkedList class it appears that `addLast` actually calls a method called `linkLast` which is:

```
void linkLast(E e) {
    final Node<E> l = last;
    final Node<E> newNode = new Node<>(l, e, null);
    last = newNode;
    if (l == null)
        first = newNode;
    else
        l.next = newNode;
    size++;
    modCount++;
}
```

The relevant portion is where `last` is declared in the class `transient Node<E> last;`  it appears that the class holds a "pointer" to the last node.  It then updates with the new node given.  So, it should be O(1) regardless of the size of the list.

Comment: Ah thank you this is also very good, thanks for enlightening me to the fact it has a pointer to the last element